# How do I eat food in the dungeon?

Tags: dungeon-robber

In [Dungeon Robber](http://blogofholding.com/dungeonrobber/), I retired a 1st level character to unlock Yeoman, which allows me to buy food in town. The in-game help says that I can eat the food in the dungeon to heal. With my next character, I bought some food, but I didn't see any option to eat it after I got hurt.

How can I eat this food in the dungeon to heal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be given the option to eat food to recover when you encounter a dead end, a river, or any other place the game deems a "safe area"

Comment: Apparently at rivers too, whether they're a dead end or not.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it yet, but supposedly you can also eat food in town, and it heals you more than in the dungeon. Check out the pdf for offline play options with your friends: http://blogofholding.com/backings/dungeonrobberrules.pdf This pdf also covers the rules in depth, so it lists all the events that allow food to be eaten.

Comment: The asker didn't ask anything about playing offline with friends.

Comment: The pdf contains explanations of how things work and what the odds are, so it is quite useful for the OP in that it also covers all aspects of when food can be eaten, among other things.

Comment: In addition to linking a website, it'd be nice if you could copy and paste the relevant information, in case the page goes down.

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure if that was appropriate or not.